# What does cpu_aidle mean in Ganglia reports?

Tags: ganglia

The cpu_aidle graph mysteriously flat at roughly 12 percent on all machines reporting on a friend's cluster. Given how everything else CPU related is spiky, this seems unusual. Can anyone shed light on what that number means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [ganglia readme](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ganglia/wiki/ganglia_readme) aidle is "Percent of time since boot idle CPU". And it says this is only available for Linux.